# How can I test if two jQuery wrapped DOM elements are the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm writing a sortable list implementation in jQuery (b/c of the infamous scroll-in-div issue, any new solutions for this?). However, I don't know how to compare the elements (triggered on mousedown/mouseup) after they've been wrapped in jQuery. In prototype, it was always ele.domNode.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish in essence...

```
<div id="cheese"></div>
<div id="burger"></div>

<script>

// Some dom nodes wrapped in jquery
var ele1 = $('#cheese');
var ele2 = $('#burger');
var ele3 = $('#burger');

// Is the dom node wrapped in ele1 (#cheese) the same as in ele2 (#burger)?
if (ele1 == ele2)
{
    // Should never be true
}

// Is the dom node wrapped in ele2 (#burger) the same as in el32 (#burger)?
if (ele2 == ele3)
{
    // Should always be true
}

</script>
```

Comment: e-motiv's answer here is great and not mentioned on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407825/how-to-compare-two-elements-in-jquery

Comment: This question from *2010* is a **duplicate** of a question from *2013*?  Hmmm, must be some weird quantum light cone stuff I don't understand.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

A jQuery object can be treated as an array of raw DOM elements.

You can compare the raw DOM elements like this:

```
if(ele2[0] === ele3[0])
```

Comment: this works & seems to be the preferred method, thanks :s

Answer (score 14):

Compare the DOM elements inside like this:

```
if (ele1.get(0) == ele2.get(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a possible way to solve this problem.  You can compare the id attributes since they should be the exact same in your example above.

```
ele1.attr("id") == ele2.attr("id"); //returns false
ele2.attr("id") == ele3.attr("id"); //returns true
```

Comment: There is nothing gained from comparing by `id`, and calling `attr` is certainly slower than just indexing into jQuery objects.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I just thought I'd share a solution that also works with no consideration for performance in comparison with other solutions since the OP did not say he was looking for the fastest solution.

Comment: And it won't work if the elements have no id..