# how to compare two elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
var a=$('#start > div:last-child');
var b=$('#start > div.live')[0];
alert(a==b)
alert(a==$(b))
```

It's always false. How can you compare two elements in jQuery?

thanks

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You could compare DOM elements. Remember that jQuery selectors return arrays which will never be equal in the sense of reference equality.

Assuming:

```
<div id="a" class="a"></div>
```

this:

```
$('div.a')[0] == $('div#a')[0]
```

returns true.

Comment: Have you tested this? I'm pretty sure it won't return true because of the differences in the `.selector` property.

Comment: Yes, I've tested this code on IE6, FF 3.6 and Chrome 4. It returns `true` on all these browsers.

Comment: See the comment below by @R-U-Bn. The following does the trick: a.is(b)

Comment: @mikeycgto using array index notation is the same as `.get()`, not `.eq()`. they are very different.

Comment: This comparison won't work. Please see the answer by R-U-Bn

Comment: See the other answer below, using [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Answer (score 367):

For the record, jQuery has an [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function for this:

```
a.is(b)
```

Note that `a` is already a jQuery instance.

Comment: This method also has the advantage of working where the "==" solution doesn't: `$(event.target).is($("#a"))`

Comment: @DanielS I don't think your 2 added "$(..)" are required here, since in the question a and b are already jquery instances. I also just mention it for other people who might think you have to double load.

Comment: If you have elemA that is a jQuery variable that represents an object `<div id=elemA><p></p></div>`, and you create elemB using `var divNode = document.createElement("div"); var pNode = document.createElement("p"); var elemB = $(divNode).html(pNode);`, these do NOT appear as equal/make an `if` statement equal true when you do `if (elemA.is(elemB)) { .... } `.  This did not work for me.

Comment: @Tyson also `$("#a").is(event.target)` works and uses one less jQuery object.

Answer (score 13):

Every time you call the jQuery() function, a new object is created and returned. So even equality checks on the same selectors will fail.

```
<div id="a">test</div>

$('#a') == $('#a') // false
```

The resulting jQuery object contains an array of matching elements, which are basically native DOM objects like `HTMLDivElement` that always refer to the same object, so you should check those for equality using the array index as Darin suggested.

```
$('#a')[0] == $('#a')[0] // true
```

Answer (score 10):

```
a.is(b)
```

and to check if they are not equal use

```
!a.is(b)
```

as for

```
$b = $('#a')
....
$('#a')[0] == $b[0] // not always true
```

maybe class added to the element or removed from it after the first assignment

Comment: a.not(b) is not the inverse of a.is(b) rather it removes elements b from a. Instead use !a.is(b)

Answer (score 2):

Random AirCoded example of testing "set equality" in jQuery:

```
$.fn.isEqual = function($otherSet) {
  if (this === $otherSet) return true;
  if (this.length != $otherSet.length) return false;
  var ret = true;
  this.each(function(idx) { 
    if (this !== $otherSet[idx]) {
       ret = false; return false;
    }
  });
  return ret;
};

var a=$('#start > div:last-child');
var b=$('#start > div.live')[0];

console.log($(b).isEqual(a));
```

Answer (score -1):

The collection results you get back from a jQuery collection do not support set-based comparison.  You can use compare the individual members one by one though, there are no utilities for this that I know of in jQuery.