# Why does my comparison of two selectors never work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple Javascript (and Jquery) that runs when an `<a>` element is clicked

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var element = $($(this).attr("href"));

    var position;

    // If the href refers to #test

    if(element == $("#test"))
    {
      position = element.offset() + element.height();

      console.log("Successful");
    }

    else
    {
      position = element.offset().top;
    }
}
```

The `if` comparison never seems to work even when the value of `element` is equal to `$("#test")` in the console and, therefore, it always jumps to the else condition.

It may be worth mentioning that when using breakpoints, both values (`element` and `$("#test")`) are equal to the following

```
w.fn.init [section#test.main.special]
```

What is the reason my comparison is not working?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2407825/5768908

Comment: What is `var element = $($(this).attr("href"))` supposed to achieve?

Comment: `$("#test")` is a jQuery selector that hasn't been paired with any functionality. If you wish to do a check directly on the attribute, then compare it to a string version of the attribute directly. `if(element == "#test") { //code goes here }`.

Answer (score 1):

use it as a string

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var getHref = $(this).attr("href").trim();

    var element = $(getHref);

    var position;

    // If the href refers to #test

    if(getHref == "#test")
    {
      position = element.offset().top + element.height();

      console.log("Successful");
    }

    else
    {
      position = element.offset().top;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is correct. Besides, I would use the triple equals for compare. if(element === "#test"). That way, you are making sure types equality.

Comment: @ILoveYouDrZaius that depends what the variable `element` ends up being *"exactly"*. Using strict equals would make it have to be two strings in comparison. The double equal is more abstract and allows different types to be compared with one another.

Comment: @Kaiido sorry I can't get your point .. what is wrong when the output of `element` href be `#test` and then use it as an id like `$(element)` `$('#test')`