# How to compare two DOM elements using Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to check if a `contenteditable` element is focused (it has the blinking caret), but this doesn't work:

```js
cy.get('span[contenteditable]').then($span => {
    cy.focused().then($focused => {
        expect($focused).to.eql($span)
    }
}
```

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `.then()` will give you an element wrapped by `jQuery`. The wrappers are not equal, but the elements are:

```js
cy.get('span[contenteditable]').should($span => {
    cy.focused().should($focused => {
        expect($focused[0]).to.eql($span[0]);
    }
}
```

I also replaced `.then()` with `.should()`. `.should()` is similar to `.then()`, except it will retry any contained assertions until they succeed or time out.

The code above is adapted from [this jQuery answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2407847/8166701).

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you want.  If you want to assert anything else about it you can add an `.and()` after the `.should()` to chain assertions.

```
  cy.focused().should('have.attr', 'contenteditable', 'true');
```

Comment: Thanks! So, it's not possible to compare the two elements directly?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but I'd be happy to be corrected if you do find a way

Answer (score 1):

A similar but cleaner solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/53233107/787333

```
cy.get('span[contenteditable]').should($span => {
    cy.focused().should($focused => {
        expect($focused[0] === $span[0]), 'span is focussed').to.be.true;
    }
}
```

Strict Equality is very simple and clean. eql() also works but does a deep comparison of every property. So it doesn't actually test identity of nodes. In practice this won't make a difference though.

Comment: Is true reference equality is all that's needed (which is `.eq()` rather than `.eql()`). But `===` is better known.

Answer (score 0):

The spirit of your question seems to be, "How do I test that an element is focused using Cypress?" (I stumbled upon this question taking the same approach you did.)

[Cypress added more explicit support for testing focus in 2019.](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/97)

You can now simply do this:

```js
cy.get('span[contenteditable]').should('have.focus');
```