# Find a cloned element by it's original DOM reference element

Tags: javascript, dom, clonenode

I have a `<template>` with several child elements in it. I'm [cloning these child elements via `.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#avoiding_documentfragment_pitfall) and appending them to `document.head`.

```
<template id="my_template">
    <script>
    // …
    </script>
</template>
```

```
var template=document.getElementById('my_template');
document.head.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
```

### What I want

Is there a way to tell at any given moment whether `document.head` already contains the `<template>` contents?

### What I tried

- Maintaining a flag e.g. `template.setAttribute('data-cloned', 1)` works, but is a workaround
- [`document.head.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) doesn't work probably because a cloned element is internally different:

  ```
  for (var i=0; i<template.content.children.length; i++) {
      document.head.contains(template.content.children[i]); // always false
  }
  ```
- looping through every template element against every element inside `document.head`, and comparing them using [`.is()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407825/how-to-compare-two-elements-in-jquery/9621817#9621817), or their [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) doesn't seem to be very effective.

I'm using the flag attribute right now, but am curious to see if there is a way to accomplish this by only using the template contents and the `document.head` without creating attribute or className clutter and/or additionally modifying them. I would like to avoid relying on jQuery as long as it's possible and reasonable.

Comment: There's nothing that links an element and its clones.

Comment: Add a unique class to an element in the template. Then use `document.head.querySelector(".thatclass")`

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the suggestion, I updated the question. I'm curious to know if this is doable without any additional classes or attributes. If not, I'll just stick with the template flag attribute

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's nothing built-in that will do this.

Comment: you could use IDs to identify them and CLASSes to group them ... and for short cuts you can use local storage to store them ...